# Elegant and efficient way to repeatedly merge dataframes into single column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a set of dataframes containing key,value pairs (as columns), where each has a subset of the keys.  I'd like to merge them all together into a single value column of an initial dataframe with keys from the same key space (with additional columns to be preserved).

For example, given:

df:

```
   key   a
0    1  A1
1   20  A2
2   33  A3
3   44  A4
```

df2:

```
   key  value
0    1  V21
1   20  NaN
2   33  V23
3   44  NaN
4   55  V25
```

df3:

```
   key  value
0    1  NaN
1   20  V32
```

I can do:

```
df['value'] = ''
df2.dropna(inplace=True)
df3.dropna(inplace=True)
df.loc[df.key.isin(df2.key), 'value'] = df2.value
df.loc[df.key.isin(df3.key), 'value'] = df3.value
```

and get the result I want:

```
   key   a  value
0    1  A1  V21
1   20  A2  V32
2   33  A3  V23
3   44  A4
```

The keys are int64 and the values are object (str).

The problem is that when I use this scheme on a larger df dataframe, result is that the value column is set to NaNs (on Pandas 0.13 & 0.14)

For example: (data available here: [df.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/meta_dl/eyJzdWJfcGF0aCI6ICIiLCAidGVzdF9saW5rIjogZmFsc2UsICJzZXJ2ZXIiOiAiZGwuZHJvcGJveHVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsICJpdGVtX2lkIjogbnVsbCwgImlzX2RpciI6IGZhbHNlLCAidGtleSI6ICJyNzdmajNqOGp6cnNnb2wifQ/AAMY9NezWTa4v1rGZH6U2dENP0_xo8S73JRUY3wLfIX96Q?dl=1) &  [common.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/meta_dl/eyJzdWJfcGF0aCI6ICIiLCAidGVzdF9saW5rIjogZmFsc2UsICJzZXJ2ZXIiOiAiZGwuZHJvcGJveHVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsICJpdGVtX2lkIjogbnVsbCwgImlzX2RpciI6IGZhbHNlLCAidGtleSI6ICJxaTRyYnBmYnBseGVtdm4ifQ/AAP29aTjNHhpt1LLPyS9-rUV6qoVWn-gXm97cMqI3yVYFw?dl=1) )

```
# read data - both pre-sorted by key
df = pandas.read_csv('df.csv')  # ~110MB / ~3M rows
common = pandas.read_csv('common.csv')  # 83 rows

all(common.key.isin(df.key))   # True - all keys in common are in df

df['value']=''  # new col of empty strings

df.loc[df.key.isin(common.key), 'value'] = common.value  # set select df values (?)

any(common.value.isin(df.value))  # False - no values from common are in df (!)

all(pandas.isnull(df.value) | (df.value=='') )  # True - all either '' or null/NaN
```

Appreciate any help on how to achieve the desired result.

### Update:

As pointed out by @Jeff, this is not a Pandas bug, but the intended behavior.  When assigning a Pandas object (e.g. a DataFrame) to a 'slice' of a DataFrame (e.g. returned by .loc as above), Pandas attempts to 'align' the indices of the two.  That is, it assigns the rows on the RHS to rows on the LHS by their Pandas index.

In my case above, the RHS has a simple integer sequential index - row numbers, and the LHS index is a subset of the selected row numbers from df (- i.e. df also has a sequential integer index, of which the slice selects a subset).  For rows on the LHS for which there is no matching index on the RHS, Pandas assigns NA.

The elegant solution is to have both df and common indexed by the content of the key column instead.  Then the assignment will do as planned - assign rows from the RHS to the LHS based on value of the key.  This is both more natural and avoids needing to pre-sort or subset.

The reason the answer of @ct-zhu works is that accessing the .values attribute of the RHS returns a Numpy array, which has no notion of a Panda-style index.  When Pandas receives such an object on the RHS, it does the assignment without trying to align indices (- which works since my example pre-arranged for the two to be in the same order via sorting)

Comment: Its unclear to me how you want to handle the Dataframes. Your example doesnt seem correct since the last operation should assign the `NaN` value at `key 1` from `df3` to the `value` column, overriding the previous value (`V21`) from `df2`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Rutger - thanks - was missing lines to dropna() from df2/df3 so that doesn't happen.  The test case with the larger data doesn't contain NAs for simplicity, but I'd like to handle them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on what you just described, should it be a classic case of `merge`? For your real case data:

```
In [6]:

print pd.merge(df, common, left_on='key', right_on='key')
           key       a             datetime             value
0   3559045188  455.22  2013-01-03 02:18:00  0584e46e2ccefa0c
1   3559045189  378.23  2013-01-03 02:19:00  df15f61e8d2dbbd4
2   3559045191   13.49  2013-01-03 04:46:00  bc75d05dae4a1aaf
3   3559045192    7.69  2013-01-03 04:48:00  41db9e3f3c9996e0
4   3559045398  641.10  2013-01-02 22:45:00  4933d72213672819
5   3559045401  548.41  2013-01-02 22:49:00  f698ef75efda0af8
6   3559045412    6.22  2013-01-02 23:12:00  3d48cc4c1d0b6f26
7   3559045414   54.97  2013-01-02 23:19:00  a9b2b5b33be185a1
8   3559045417  275.95  2013-01-02 23:22:00  1a59cfcf32351d81
9   3559045418  407.95  2013-01-02 23:22:00  af81dac601f02f36
10  3559045419   10.00  2013-01-02 23:23:00  849a2fa3e46a0f2e
           ...     ...                  ...               ...

[83 rows x 4 columns]
```

Should be a comment but I want to show the resulting dataframe

Also, to combine `df2` and `df3` (shown in the first half or your question) together, use `pd.concat((df2, df3)).dropna()`. If you have duplicated key, you need to `.drop_duplicate()`, but it dependents on which value you are planning to keep.

## Edit:

You can do what you described with just one additional `values`:

```
In [77]:

DF=df.copy()
DF['value']=np.nan
DF.ix[df.key.isin(common.key),'value']=common.ix[common.key.isin(DF.key), 'value'].values
#Assume their are both sorted and common may contain keys df doesn't.
print DF.dropna().head(10)
                key       a             datetime             value
2364554  3559045188  455.22  2013-01-03 02:18:00  0584e46e2ccefa0c
2364555  3559045189  378.23  2013-01-03 02:19:00  df15f61e8d2dbbd4
2364557  3559045191   13.49  2013-01-03 04:46:00  bc75d05dae4a1aaf
2364558  3559045192    7.69  2013-01-03 04:48:00  41db9e3f3c9996e0
2364764  3559045398  641.10  2013-01-02 22:45:00  4933d72213672819
2364767  3559045401  548.41  2013-01-02 22:49:00  f698ef75efda0af8
2364778  3559045412    6.22  2013-01-02 23:12:00  3d48cc4c1d0b6f26
2364780  3559045414   54.97  2013-01-02 23:19:00  a9b2b5b33be185a1
2364783  3559045417  275.95  2013-01-02 23:22:00  1a59cfcf32351d81
2364784  3559045418  407.95  2013-01-02 23:22:00  af81dac601f02f36

[10 rows x 4 columns]
```

This may be a bug. I am not sure.
But adding one `common` at a time is very inefficient, as the `isin` has takes a lot of time for the very big `df` dataframe. It takes almost 3s on my machine.

Comment: the above results in 83 rows, but I need the full 3121970 rows of df as I want to do this repeatedly with thousands of 'common' dataframes, rather than just two (df2 & df3) as in the toy example.  While with only 2 dataframes I could just use merge(...,how='left'), doing that repeatedly doesn't combine the value column, it just adds additional columns value_x, value_y, ...  A way to combine these via selecting the non-NaN value would work (- explicit iteration is too slow)

Comment: Very helpful update. Is it feasible to `concat` all the **common_i** dataframes into one first? Or in real application the **common_i** dataframes will come in real time and the new data need to be added into the dataframe every time a new **common_i** comes in?

Comment: You can do what you described with a very small change and not getting all `nan` in the end, but it is very slow. See edit.

Comment: Indeed, since `common` doesn't contain keys not in `df`, it also works as `=common.ix[:,'value'].values` or even using `loc` instead of `ix`.  It may indeed be a Pandas bug (I'll file a report), but your solution works! Thank you @ct-zhu!  In my actual use-case, the common dataframes are from a dataset much too large to fit into memory and have been split, but the dataset from which the df is drawn has been split to fit into memory and doesn't need to be re-combined.  I'm essentially trying to do an on-disk left join, but without needing to re-combine the left table from its partitions.